# EJB3.1 JSF2.0 CDI ejbRef conversion

Tags: java-ee-6

I am developping a project using JSF2.0/Primefaces, EJB3.1, Hibernate.
I created an enterprise application, injected EJB3 Facades into JSF Managed Beans using CDI and created web pages that call the managed beans. When i run the project i am able to list data rows and view row details but the problem appears when i select one row from the datatable and click edit or remove button.

```
SEVERE: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.procc.jpa.Alert.responseCollection, could not initialize proxy - no Session
SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to convert ejbRef for ejb AlertFacade to a business object of type interface com.procc.dao.AlertFacadeLocal
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EjbContainerServicesImpl.getBusinessObject(EjbContainerServicesImpl.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.weld.ejb.SessionObjectReferenceImpl.getBusinessObject(SessionObjectReferenceImpl.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:108)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:105)
    at com.procc.dao.AlertFacade$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.remove(AlertFacade$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.java)
    at com.procc.backing.AlertController.persist(AlertController.java:118)
    at com.procc.backing.AlertController.delete(AlertController.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:148)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1093)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

This is code snippet:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "alertController")
@SessionScoped
public class AlertController extends AbstractController<Alert> implements Serializable {

@Inject private AlertFacadeLocal ejbFacade;
private Class<Alert> itemClass;
private Alert selected;
private List<Alert> items;

private enum PersistAction {
    CREATE,
    DELETE,
    UPDATE
}

public AlertController(){
    itemClass = Alert.class;
}

public void delete(ActionEvent event) {
    String msg = ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString(itemClass.getSimpleName() + "Deleted");
    persist(AlertController.PersistAction.DELETE, msg);
    if (!isValidationFailed()) {
        selected = null; // Remove selection
        items = null; // Invalidate list of items to trigger re-query.
    }
}

private void persist(AlertController.PersistAction persistAction, String successMessage) {
    if (selected != null) {
        this.setEmbeddableKeys();
        try {
            if (persistAction != AlertController.PersistAction.DELETE) {
                this.ejbFacade.edit(selected);
            } else {
                this.ejbFacade.remove(selected);
            }
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(successMessage);
        } catch (EJBException ex) {
            String msg = "";
            Throwable cause = JsfUtil.getRootCause(ex.getCause());
            if (cause != null) {
                msg = cause.getLocalizedMessage();
            }
            if (msg.length() > 0) {
                JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(msg);
            } else {
                JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(ex, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(ex, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        }
    }
}
```

In JSF page i got:

```
<p:panel header="#{bundle.ListAlertTitle}" style="border:0px;">

    <p:dataTable id="datalist" value="#{alertController.items}" var="item"
                     selectionMode="single" selection="#{alertController.selected}"
                     rowKey="#{item.alertId}"
                     paginator="true"
                     rows="10"
                     rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30"
                     >

        <p:ajax event="rowSelect"   update="viewButton editButton deleteButton"/>
        <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="viewButton editButton deleteButton"/>
    <p:column sortBy="#{item.alertId}" filterBy="#{item.alertId}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListAlertTitle_alertId}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.alertId}"/>
    </p:column>
....
<p:commandButton id="viewButton"   icon="ui-icon-search" value="#{bundle.View}" update=":AlertViewForm" oncomplete="AlertViewDialog.show()" disabled="#{empty alertController.selected}"/>
<p:commandButton id="editButton"   icon="ui-icon-pencil" value="#{bundle.Edit}" update=":AlertEditForm" oncomplete="AlertEditDialog.show()" disabled="#{empty alertController.selected}"/>
<p:commandButton id="deleteButton" icon="ui-icon-trash"  value="#{bundle.Delete}" actionListener="#{alertController.delete}" update=":growl,datalist" disabled="#{empty alertController.selected}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange error!
I tryed to do an explicit conversion to AirportFacade and that solved the problem!! I don't know why could'nt it do the implicit conversion? and why does it need conversion from first place ??

```
if (persistAction != PersistAction.DELETE) {
    ((AirportFacade)ejbFacade).edit(selected);
} else {
    ((AirportFacade)ejbFacade).remove(selected);
}
```

Please, if anybody got the answer let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Thank you.